# Trouble looping over multi-dimensional dict

Tags: python, python-2.4

Using python 2.4:

How can I iterate over this data structure:

```
if device not in alerts:
    alerts[device] = {}
alerts[device]['mntpt'] = mntpt
alerts[device][timestamp] = { 'r_ops': r_ops, 'r_avgrtt': r_avgrtt, 'r_avgexe': r_avgexe, 'w_ops': w_ops, 'w_avgrtt': w_avgrtt, 'w_avgexe': w_avgexe }
```

I want to do some calculations on the values in the timestamps dicts for each device.

Thx for any help...

Comment: Is it `timestamp` of `'timestamp'`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what is the problem? Please show your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for device in alerts:
    for timestamp in alerts[device]:
        #Do stuff with timestamp
```

Comment: No point to dereference this way collection for the 2nd loop. Just use `for timestamp in device:`

Comment: But `timestamp` is not a member of `device`, it's a member of `alerts[device]`.  Either I'm misunderstanding you or I disagree.

Comment: `alerts` is a dictionary containing nested dictionaries. In the 2nd loop you are just assigning to `timestamp` variable one of these nested dictionaries referred by `device` key assigned in the outer loop. The `timestamp` var in OP's question is unrelated to your example.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I've reread OP's a bit unclear question and find your answer correct.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, actually stumbled upon that after posting.. Thx for the info. btw what is with the creepy creeps down voting a legitimate question? They obviously didn't search for this *exact* depth of iteration because I did. /facepalm